# is it possible to use jquery-ui-timepicker in infobox of google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infobox, jquery-ui-timepicker

firstly myself new to java script as well as jquery.i am having a task to be done i.e in google maps when we click on an specific area(polygon,circle) a infowindow needs to be opened with some styles.So i moved to infobox and added some css(jquery custom css ui lightness).in that infobox i need to show calender with time.so i done a lot of RD and writen code

i writen the code by using drawing tools,infobox,jquery custom css,jquery-ui-timepicker

Now my problem is jquery-ui-timepicker is not raising in infobox. if i am using it with in a normal div its working fine.

here is some of my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
    });
</script>

 var contentString =
                 '<table width="100%"' +
                 '<tr>' + '<td width="18%">From Date:</input></td>' + '<td> <input class="datetimepicker" id="start_time" name="start_time" type="text" /></td>' + '<td width="18%" align="center">To Date:</input></td>' + '<td><input class="datetimepicker" id="end_time" name="end_time" type="text" /></td>' + '</tr>' +
                 '</table>'

 function RaiseInfoWindow() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingModesType, 'click', function (event) {
            if (infoBox)
                infoBox.close();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            message = GetMessage(drawingModesType);
            InfoBoxType(InfoBox, message);
            infoBox.setOptions({ content: message });
            infoBox.setPosition(bounds.getCenter());
            infoBox.open(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(infoBox, 'domready', function () {
                jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        });
function GetMessage(polygon) {
        coordinates = polygon.getPath().getArray();
        message = ['<div id="tabs">', '<ul>', '<li><a href="#tab-1" ><span>Modify</span></a></li>', '<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Save</span></a></li>', '</ul>',
           '<div id="tab-1">', '<li><div style="color:#000" class="divText" >Approximately area is ' + GetAreaInAcres(polygon) + ' kms</div></li>', '<div class="divbuttonText"><p><input type="button" value="Edit" title="Edit" class="buttonStyle" onclick="ShapeEditable(true);" />' + "     " + '<input type="button" value="Done" title="Done" class="buttonStyle" onclick="ShapeEditable(false);" />' + "     " + '<input type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" class="buttonStyle" onclick="DeleteShape(drawingModesType);" /></p></div>', '</div>',
           '<div id="tab-2">', '<p>' + contentString + '</p>', '</div>', '</div>'].join('');
        return message;
    }
```

**Update**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raviteja0664/vfbJg/2/)
Here Is my Jsfiddle with my complete code(dont think that i got mad. i tried to add the script url but its not working.i saw so many jsfiddles( which are given examples with jquery-ui-timepicker addon .js,there also same problem)so i added the script.my code starts from 2199 line.please neglect the before lines)

**Update2:**

[here is my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raviteja0664/LDnxw/1/) after applying the @gaurrav suggestion time picker is raising but it is raising after 2 to 3 clicks

Comment: i see timepicker working with input field,, can you point me towards infobox, i cant find it on map

Comment: @Dave ya its working with input field.but it is not working inside infobox.and what u mean cant find it on map

Comment: usually in map there is marker, on click of marker the infobox pops up.. so here no marker,, where is infobox,, point me towards it

Comment: @Dave i am not using any marker..using drawing tools so u just draw a polygon and click inside of it.a infobox will be raise i the second tab u can find the input fields.there i am facing the problem

Comment: so your problem is that,, infobox is not getting displayed basically ?

Comment: @Dave infoxbox will display just follow the above steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoBox is created dyanamically when the map loads, so '$(".datetimepicker")' won't be able to find your div. Try using '$("body").find(".datetimepicker")'.

Comment: @gaurraw5 thanks for your reply.i added find(".datetimepicker") to my code but no change.

Comment: is there any marker on which you are setting your infoBox or infowindow?

Comment: just make it $("body").on("click",".datetimepicker",function(){ $(this).datetimepicker({}); });

Comment: @gaurraw its working($("body").on("click",".datetimepicker",function(){ $(this).datetimepicker({}); });)but having a small issue it is raisng after 2 to 3 clicks.